# Analysis of causal relationship of within-subject choice patterns among different groups using R - emmeans / hlm / Mixed Effects Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear, lsmeans, choice-modeling

I am conducting a research and investigate the relationship between persona type (independent variable; a vs. b vs. c vs. d) and luxury perfume choice (dependent variable; niche vs prestige)(H1), moderated by brand prominence (loud vs quiet) (H2).

At the start of the questionnaire each participant assigned a specific Persona (A, B, C, or D). In the survey, there were two choice moments:

The first choice moment (H1) gives the participant a choice between two images (0 (prestige) and 1 (niche), respectively), with "Prominence" being 0.
The second choice moment (H2) gives the participant another choice between two images (0 (niche) and 1 (prestige), respectively), with "Prominence" being 1.

I would like to examine the causal relationship between the variables Persona (independent variable), Prominence (moderator), and Choice (dependent variable). Specifically, I am interested in understanding the dominant choices made by individuals within each Persona, both for Choice and Prominence, and if this choice/mean is significant.

I have already performed a Mixed Effects Logistic Regression analysis with the following formula:
model <- glmer(Choice ~ Prominence + Persona + (1 | ID), data = mydata, family = binomial)

This analysis provided me with general results regarding the effects of Prominence and Persona on Choice. However, I want to further refine the results by specifically examining the choice patterns within each Persona. Hence, I tried to run emmeans but got error message "Error in emmeans(model, ~Persona + Choice) :
No variable named Choice in the reference grid " .

My specific questions are:

How can I specify the choice patterns for Choice within each Persona separately? For example, I want to know which choice (0 or 1) is predominantly made within Persona A, Persona B, Persona C, and Persona D.

Similarly, I want to specify the choice patterns for Prominence within each Persona separately. I want to determine at which value of Prominence (0 or 1) the choice of 0 or 1 is predominantly made within Persona A, Persona B, Persona C, and Persona D.

I am seeking assistance in specifying these analyses in R so that I can understand the choice patterns within each Persona in more detail. Any help and suggestions that can contribute to analyzing these specific choice patterns within my dataset are greatly appreciated. Note that this is my first time running an analysis ever and am not familiar with R or any other tool.

Any help or advice would be very appreciated!
Thank you,
Marie

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the `emmeans` call, you can specify only predictor (independent) variables. Seems like you want `Persona` there. The dependent variable is understood from the model.

You mention that `Prominence` is a moderator, and if you think that it is influenced by `Persona`, consider adding `cov.reduce = Prominence~Persona` to the call. This will cause it to use a different mean prominence for each persona, rather than the same overall mean prominence.